# Qt Creator C++ WASM build takes 4 minutes even when no changes were made. Why?

Tags: qt, deployment, webassembly

When I build without WASM, if there were no changes made, the build time is less than a second. But when I build for WASM, it takes about 4 minutes every time.

It seems to me it may have something to do with "deployment." This doesn't make sense to me, because, to me, "deployment" means uploading the files to my website, which I do through my web hosting service. I have not told Qt Creator anything about my website. So what is "build/deploy" doing?

Can I tell Qt Creator to just build without deploy? And what is it trying to do to "deploy" anyway?

Comment: Just speculating, but it may be related to statically linking in the entire Qt framework (at least all the used parts) into one wasm binary (for native applications people usually link Qt dynamically). Note, I've noticed that debug builds are quite a bit faster for Qt WebAssembly applications, so at least some of the time comes from compiler optimizations.

Comment: @Karmo I suspect you are right. More specifically, I am guessing that because Qt Creator does not have access to the the dependency data for the entire Qt library, to know if it has changed since the last build, it builds that static build every time, even when no changes at all were made. And I see there is no easy way for Qt to get around that. Thank you for your great "speculation."